# Full Revaluation vs Factor-based Model for risk management

Tags: risk-management, factor-models, valuation, risk-models

I am looking for literature on comparison of these two approaches.

It looks like many places are using some type of Factor-based Model (Barra, Axioma, Northfield, etc.) for risk management purposes. Given this and emerging Multi-Asset Class risk models based on set risk factors, will there be a place for Full Revaluation in the future? Or do we expect standardized risk factors, which will be suitable for complex, multi asset portfolios?

Any thoughts/opinions appreciated!

Comment: What is “full revaluation” ?

Comment: pricing/valuation of an instrument using its valuation model parameters. So for BSM model based options, the option price is calculated using the underlying price, strike price, implied/historical volatility, interest rate, dividend rate ...

Comment: ok so then i am not sure what is the relation with Barra here ? Barra is used to decompose an equity portfolio risk whereas derivatives portfolio use the model parameters for the non-delta part of the risk. So in that sense each “approach” of risk management (in your words) is just used for different purpose, they are not alternative to each other...

Comment: Factor-based models can decompose any type of asset class if you know/tell how to do them. Then these risk models become an alternative to full reval based risk models. Even if you take a simple equity portfolio and calculate its VaR using factor-based risk model and compare it to full reval based VaR, there is a high probability that the result will be different. Was just curious if there was a work that discusses this.

Comment: I still dont understand what is for you the full reval risk of an equity portfolio, can you explain this at least ?

Comment: Think of a simulation models (Historical or Monte Carlo) -- these model perform full revaluation and derive VaR. Makes sense?

Comment: I think by full revaluation you meant something like approximating/having analytical form of posterior distribution?